# Error Installing Scikit-learn in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, scikit-learn

Getting the following error when trying to install scikit-learn using pip

Error:

```
Downloading/unpacking scikit-learn

  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement scikit-learn

Cleaning up...

No distributions at all found for scikit-learn
Storing debug log for failure in /home/dmacs/.pip/pip.log
```

I've even tried with proxy setting as :

```
sudo pip --proxy http://user:pass@localhost:port install scikit-learn
```

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of pip are you using? Just in case: `pip --version`

Comment: Something interesting could be here: `/home/dmacs/.pip/pip.log`

Comment: I'm currently using pip 1.5.4

Answer (score 1):

Based on the details:

a. The server where you are installing has a networking issue which doesnt seem to solve by the proxy command. Basically it is unable to download the list from pip.

b. If networking is running kindly try this:

```
sudo pip install -U pip
sudo pip install -U scikit-learn
```